# Synology NAS Multimedia content migration

Tags: nas, storage, synology, multimedia, data-migration

I'm about to replace my current DiskStation with a new one with more disk space. In the process, I'll move from 6GB JBOD to 10GB RAID storage.

Since my current NAS is nearly full, I have a lot of data to migrate. I understand that the migration assistant is meant to do the job in a safe and robust manner, and I expect the transfer to take several days. Now, [from prior readings](https://www.synology.com/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_migrate_between_Synology_NAS_DSM_6_0_and_later) on the Synology web site, I have two questions:

- Will the migration assistant also migrate all multimedia metadata, thumbnails, etc, so I find again the complete libraries for Video, Photo and Audio Station on the new NAS? Reindexing everything and retrieving metadata would be disastrous, as that would be years of fine-tuning and correction lost. That's especially true for thumbnails, as I have countless pictures.
- I see that it's recommended to connect the two servers directly with an ethernet cable. That makes sense and I see the benefit of not going through the router. However, only the new NAS has two ethernet ports, so I expect that the old one will not be available on the network, since it will only be connected to the new one, so that no data will be available until the migration is complete. Is that correct?

Thanks in advance!

R.

Comment: What does Synology have to say about it?

Comment: Nothing, hence my question...

Comment: Did you contact their support?